# Deserialize binary data that i don't have the original scheme for?

Tags: serialization, binary, reverse-engineering

i have a server emulator for a game I'm working on, and it sends data to the backend in forms of binary, is there a way to deserialize this binary data to be able to parse it? even if I don't have the original class or struct?